# Putting cache entries to specific Ignite Server

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain

I have an Ignite data grid of five servers(say A,B,C,D and E). A partitioned cache has been distributed across these five servers with the number of backups set as 1.

I want to store 100 million entries in this partitioned cache. But, I want to control the partitioning of my cache entries to the Ignite servers.

Is it possible that I can direct my Ignite client to put a cache entry on a particular server (say E)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to implement your own [Affinity Function](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/AffinityFunction.html) instead of the ones provided out of the box. However, I would encoredge you to rethink this approach because it's not scalable. Affinity functions included in Ignite are designed to provide even distribution on any set of nodes, so you can dynamically scale up and down whenewer you need this. Your approach is much less flexible.

Also I would recommend you to go through documentation page about [Affinity Collocation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation). Very likely this will give you hints on how to implement your logic in a better way.

And fincally, can you give some more details about your use case? I will be happy to give some advice on how to approach it.

Comment: I am actually trying to use Apache Ignite to create a bloom filter for which I require a distributed array of 100 billion bits. Since, Ignite doesn't support a distributed array data structure,I am trying to break the array into small bit sets and storing them as cache entries. I wanted to control the distribution as it would have helped me in deciding which server has a specific cache entry  and direct my compute jobs (using Ignite Compute grid) to that particular server. Is there any way that I can get the node UUID of a server given a particular key?

Comment: I just found that it is possible to get the partition on which a particular key is present using the function CacheConfiguration().getAffinityFunction().partition(Object key). Can you tell me now that is it possible to find the UUID of the Ignite server that has this partition?

Comment: This should be done through `Affinity` API which can be acquired via `Ignite.affinity()` method. But to send a collocated closure you can simply use `IgniteCompute.affinityRun()` and `IgniteCompute.affinityCall()` methods.

Comment: Since there is no way to figure out the Ignite server that holds a key in an Ignite Cluster.Would Entry processor be a good choice for doing affinity runs for keys?

Comment: I just gave you the way :) Use `Affinity` API to manually calculate the mapping. I only meant that `affinityRun()`, `affinityCall()` will do this work for you automatically. These methods also make sure that partitions are not evicted before your computation is completed.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin :)